# Raspberry Pi: Remote desktop with tightvnc and mac

Tags: macos, raspbian, tightvnc

I am trying to setup tightvnc on my Raspberry Pi 2 (rp2), so I can remote in from my mac. I have done this before and it went smooth as butter. But this second setup has been a real challenge and i am not sure why. I used these steps: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/. The only thing I did wrong on this - I setup automatic start up before ever connecting to the vnc server or setting up the password, which makes me think might be the root of the problem.

When I try to connect to my rp2 via finder's connect to server feature, I get a message saying that I cannot connect and need to check the settings on the host. I can ssh into rp2, and i can see that indeed tightvnc is not running, but! .X0-lock and X0 in /tmp/ folder do exist. If I delete both of these and restart tightvnc and then connect to the rp2 from my mac I can see grey pixelated screen & mouse cursor. ???

I tried removing tightvnc, tried disabling autostart, but it always persists which is beyond me (i have used linux before for school and work, so I am not a complete noob, but not an expert either). I tried redoing the steps to correct the install, no luck.

Any ideas? Any thing I can take a look at? I might just wipe the whole raspberry instal.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you redo the link to the instructions? it appears to have gotten modified/corrupted and does not work.

Comment: @RichardChambers fixed!

Comment: The documentation describes two phases for getting tightvnc setup. The first phase is to install tightvnc and then configure the server application by starting it up and setting up the geometry, and view port settings. The second step is once you have a functioning tightvnc server that you can start up by hand that will use the configuration you specified is to then create a script that when the Pi boots, one of the services automatically started is the tightvnc server. Can you ssh into your Pi and start the tightvnc server manually?

Comment: You may also want to look at http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server

Comment: once i ssh in, if i try to start the vnc server right away, i get this  Warning: raspberrypi:0 is taken because of /tmp/.X0-lock
Remove this file if there is no X server raspberrypi:0
A VNC server is already running as :0

Comment: I can then delete temp files and restart the server, but when i connect to it - all i see is grey and grey cursor.